# Set the limit of sent / received packets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

My vps server provider limits me to 50,000 packets per second. After exceeding the number of packets, the link speed slows down to 1Mbit / s. Is it possible to set the ubuntu system not to exceed 50,000 packets per second?

Comment: The jargon for that is probably “traffic shaping”. How successful traffic shaping  can be controlled from only your OS depends on the nature of your traffic (ingress is often more difficult to control than egress),  the type of VPS and your OS. -

Comment: See this question describing use of the iptables `limit` module.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163657/set-packet-rate-limit-via-iptables